# SQL Select query with Group and status (SQL server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have a table with the follwoing structure

```
id   g_id   name    status
---------------------------------------
1   111     item1   1
2   111     item2   1
3   111     item3   1

6   113     item1   -1
7   113     item2   1
8   113     item3   1

9   114     item1   1
10  114     item2   2
```

status can contains values ,
success     : 1
Failed      : -1
In progress : 2

```
Need the following output 
GroupID     Status
------------------
111         Success
113         Failed
114         In-Progress
```

If one in the group is -1, result should be Failed and if all is 1 then it should be Success. Also if some are 1 and rest is 2 result should be In Progress.
What is the best way i can select the above results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ca1a/5)

```
select
    g_id as GroupID,
    case
        when min(status) = -1 then 'failed'
        when max(status) = 2 and min(status) = 1 then 'in progress'
        when max(status) = 1 and min(status) = 1 then 'success'
    end as Status
from table1
group by g_id
```

Comment: thanks! second `when` it can also be change to when `max(status) = 2 and min(status) = 1 then 'in progress'` to exact requirements, but it works anyway. P.S. Changed it to be more structured :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to because the CASE will stop at the first match. And you should be able to optimize it by just doing `ELSE 'success'` at the end (assuming there aren't other status values)

Comment: yes I know, but it helps people to understand code if you write exact bounds :) I'm working with other developers, you know. I do not want my query to be easy brokeable by some programmer who decide to switch positions of when for some reason :)

Comment: True, or you could always throw a comment in if you're worried.

Comment: BTW I'm able to use `else` and it was written with `else` but then I decide that 3 `when` will be more useful, and OP may want to add additional `else` or `when` to `status = 3` or smth else

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.g_id, 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 x WHERE x.g_id = t.g_id AND x.status = -1) THEN 'Failed' 
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 x WHERE x.g_id = t.g_id AND x.status = 2) THEN 'In-Progress'
         ELSE 'Success' END AS Status
FROM Table1 t
GROUP BY t.g_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2be3b/2)

Answer (score 1):

A simple use of `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT g_id,  
       CASE 
          WHEN MIN(Status) = -1 THEN 'Failed'
          WHEN MAX(Status) = 2  THEN 'In Progress'
          ELSE 'Succes'
       END
    AS Status
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY g_id
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2be3b/13)